# Leaving a job to do postdoc

Tags: career-development, india, career-switch

I have recently graduated with my PhD in chemistry and have joined as an application scientist in a material analysis instrumentation company in India. The main role in this job is assisting the sales and marketing team in demonstrating the applications of the instruments to the customers.

Honestly speaking, even within two months after joining, I am finding the job pretty boring, without any scope of utilizing my research skills or growth in my career.

Therefore, I was thinking about applying for R&D jobs or doing postdoc roles to increase my research experience and applying for R&D jobs in my country or abroad later.

My question is, is it normal to join a postdoctoral position for better prospcts after leaving a job?  As an ultimate goal, I prefer to stay in industry (although in an R&D role) compared to academia.

Comment: My experience is solely in U.S. but if your goal is to stay in industry, I would *NOT* get a post-doc, it wouldn't help.  In industry, (again US), actual production is valued much more than research, so if you can try to do production-oriented work. It doesn't say what field you are in, but that's my advice.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I was wondering - is the experience in an application support job (with little to no research), helpful for persuing a career in Research scientist job in industry? My field is chamistry / materials science by the way

Comment: My experience is in software and embedded engineering.  I'd see how your peers navigated their careers, however IMHO getting a post-doc rarely helps non-academic careers.

Comment: You ask if it's normal, but what are you worried about? Whether you'll get on the post-doc, or whether future employers will think it's odd, or something else?

Comment: @Stuart F I am worried about whatbif future employers find it odd

Answer (score 4):

I would say if you enjoy chemistry and want to do a postdoc then just try and do one, irrespective if you want to return to industry or not, as you probably won't get another chance later on once you're ensconced in industry.

I'd personally try to get out of application support and back into something at least tangential to R&D.

Comment: Tgank you for your advice. But may I know what "tangential to R & D" mean? (Sorry it is just my unability to understand the phrase)

Comment: I mean a job more closely related to something in research and development - something academic would be great, maybe working on the development of an existing product, but not supporting an existing one.